# how to add link to radconfirm message

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to add hyperlink which directs to another page as text to radconfirm. The code works fine if the hyperlink is removed but the confirm window never shows up if present.

Please find the code below:

```
    strLink = "\conditions\terms.aspx"

    strMsg += "are you Sure?"
    strMsg += "<br/>"
    strMsg += "<i>"
    strMsg += "please check conditions"
    strMsg += "<a href='" + strLink + "' target='_blank'>"
    strMsg +=  "here" + "</a>"
    strMsg += "</i>"
```

radWindowMngr.RadConfirm(strMsg, "Update", 330, 100, Nothing, "")

Comment: If you have a lot of concats, take a look at `StringBuilder` class

Comment: One suggestion is you can use the RadWindow as a RadConfirm.Take a look into this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/custom-radconfirm.aspx#2631891

Answer (score 0):

i tried with your code but not able to replicate this issue.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function opnePopup() {
            var strLink = "\conditions\\terms.aspx"

            var strMsg = "are you Sure?"
            strMsg += "<br/>"
            strMsg += "<i>"
            strMsg += "please check conditions "
            strMsg += "<a href='" + strLink + "' target='_blank'>"
            strMsg += "here" + "</a>"
            strMsg += "</i>"
            radconfirm(strMsg, confirmCallBackFn, 330, 180, null, 'Client RadConfirm', '');
            return false;
        }

        function confirmCallBackFn(args) {
            alert(args);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>


            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
            <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
            <button style="width: 200px;" onclick="return opnePopup();">
                radconfirm from client</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : Please use double slash in URL (strLink).

[image][image]